# Как запихнуть в SMS побольше данных

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, arduino, sms

В текущем варианте для передачи данных посредством SMS уже приходится отправлять по нескольку SMS за раз.

Передаются списки команд в текстовом виде, например:

```
water 1 100
wait 60
send_counter 0
```

На стороне приёмника - ардуино с GSM модулем, на передающей стороне - скрипт питона, использующий небезизвестный SMS gate.

Уже сделано:

- zlib компрессия данных
- base64 кодирование

Какие есть ещё способы уместить больше данных в одной или нескольких SMS (с учетом ограничений, накладываемых на текстовые сообщения).

Comment: Вроде это зависит от `SMS` канала. да и от самого сервиса.

Comment: А какая именно информация пересылается? думаю, надо начинать плясать именно от этого... И что за софт может быть у отправителя и получателя - любой или с ограничениями?

Comment: Как минимум слова стандартные - сократить до одного символа. Типа water - w, wait - a, send_counter - s или что-то вроде. Числа - если реально есть большие :) - переводить в, скажем, 64-ричную систему счисления (букв хватит :)) Выкинуть лишние пробелы. При этом, кстати, может оказаться, что zlib+base64 только ухудшит ситуацию (кстати, а как сейчас?)

Comment: @Harry сейчас zlib+base64 короче получается на не коротких текстах. Надо будет проверить с сокращениями (тогда не нужны будут словари zlib, доп. экономия).

Comment: кроме того пробел за командой лишний. `w1 100` вполне достаточно. (при условии что команд не более 85 и символов хватит). Для чисел можно использовать даже не 64, а 85-ричную систему, правда выигрыш даст для действительно больших чисел

Comment: @Mike Да, кстати. А 85 - это исходя из ограничений на символы SMS?

Comment: На счет SMS точно не знаю, но все обычные ascii символы там проходить должны как однобайтные по идее. И на самом деле даже чуть больше 85 есть, просто base85 кодировка конечно менее распространенная, чем 64, но вполне себе рабочая и можно немного поиграть с кодовой таблицей что бы исключить нежелательные символы вроде обратной косой. Вообще в ascii 94 символа печатные, так что можно и около этого кол-ва использовать

Comment: @Mike Ну, под лишними пробелами я имел в виду именно это - w1 - а не двойные пробелы :) А вот base94, честно говоря, мне представляется излишеством - при сокращении команд скорее всего избыточность будет невелика, так что паковка может оказаться неэффективной.

Comment: Кстати, если есть какие-то более-менее стандартные длинные числовые значения, встречающиеся особенно часто - их тоже можно сократить с помощью какого-то знака - типа, #1 - это 100, #2 - 3.1416 :)